# Rally 2.1 SDK - Filtering User Stories by Iterations

Tags: javascript, json, sdk, rally

Is it possible to filter user stories based on iterations between a beginning iteration and an ending iteration. I am able to filter all user stories from the beginning iteration forward and the ending iteration backward, but I get an error when I use ".and" filter in my store object.

```
 var StartDateFilter = Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter', {
        property: 'Iteration',
        operator: '>=',
        value: StartIteration
    });


    var UserStoryFilter = StartDateFilter.and(Ext.create(
        'Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
            property: 'Iteration',
            operator: '<=', // combines the the iterations so it receives all iterations in between 
            value: EndIteration
    }));


    var UserStoryFilter = StartDateFilter.and(EndDateFilter);


    this.defectStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
        model: 'User Story', 
        autoLoad: true,                         
        pageSize: 1000,
        filters : UserStoryFilter,

        listeners: {
            load: function(myStore, myData) {
                console.log(myData); 
            },
            scope: this                         
        },
        fetch: ['CreationDate','FormattedID', 'Name', 'PlanEstimate', 'Feature', 'PortfolioItem', 'Milestones','Parent','Children']
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use it directly like you are, but you should be able to do something similar...

```
var filters = [
    {
        property: 'Iteration.StartDate',
        operator: '>=',
        value: '2018-05-01' //iso formatted iteration start date
    },
    {
        property: 'Iteration.EndDate',
        operator: '<=',
        value: '2018-06-30' //iso formatted iteration end date
    },
];
```